# Append value in a file using maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a value that I want to append at the end of a file, but I cannot figure which plugin to use.

Example:
the value I want to append: "myValue"

file:

value1

value2

**myValue** #  after append

I know I can do it using the antrun-plugin, but is it possible to do this with a maven plugin?

I've also looked over `maven-shade-plugin`, but from the few examples on their website I only saw doing append of 2 files instead of what I need (value to append to one file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say, but I think your best option really is the Ant plugin.

I shudder every time I have to use Ant in my pom.xml, but in some cases, it's the easiest option. Learn to embrace it, it will save you some headaches :-)

You could probably also write your own Maven plugin, but that would likely be more work.

One other option would be to create a shell script to append the value, and then call that using the `maven-exec-plugin`. You'll have to deal with different operating systems in that case, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [maven filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Filtering will replace a placeholder value, but it won't help with appending a new value to an existing file, unless the file already contains the placeholder.

Comment: I don't fully agree with you, @nwinkler. You can always solve this with placeholder. Even if it's empty-valued. Sure, you can also do it with the antrun plugin, but why bother in this case...? I believe filtering will do the trick here, unless the use case is a more complicated one.

Answer (score 0):

The [Codehaus gmaven-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home) is another option for tasks like these.